# i want to make table with this data (c++)

Tags: c++, matrix

i want to input table like this

1. NPM | NAME | ADDRESS
2. NPM | NAME | ADDRESS
3. NPM | NAME | ADDRESS
4. NPM | NAME | ADDRESS
5. NPM | NAME | ADDRESS

this is my code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

string kolom(int s){
    string h;
    if(s==0){
        h="NPM";
    }else if(s==1){
        h="Name";
    }else if(s==2){
        h="Address";
    }
    return h;
}
int main(){
    int m[4][3],a,b,c,i,j;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            cout<<"Input "<<kolom(j)<<endl;
            cin>>m[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

but there's problem, 
[image]

thanks

---

i have solve it with this code
but there's a problem that i dont know why my program is not working

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

string kolom(int s){
    string h;
    if(s==0){
        h="NPM";
    }else if(s==1){
        h="Name";
    }else if(s==2){
        h="Address";
    }
    return h;
}
int main(){
    int a,b,c,i,j,k;
    k=1;
    string m[4][2];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){

        cout<<"Data ke-"<<k++<<endl;
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            cout<<"Input "<<kolom(j)<<endl;
            cin>>m[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

[Second Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KghT9.png)

Comment: How would you input a *string* into an `int` value? Remember that `m[i][j]` is an `int`, it can't store a string and the input operation will fail.

Comment: May not be the exact problem , but in `for(i=0;i<5;i++)`, it should be `i<4` or it will be array out of bounds

Comment: thank you :) my bad

Comment: just change m[i][j] into a string

Comment: but now i have problem, when in last data, the program is not working

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `m` as `string m[5][3]` instead of `string m[4][2]`.

You have declared `m` as the static array of strings with **four** rows and **two** columns. Thus, the numbers of rows are {0, 1, 2, 3} and the numbers of columns are {0, 1}.

However, in your outer loop `i` changes from 0 to 4 (e.g. i={0, 1, 2, 3, **4**}). Index 4 is reached on the last iteration and it is out of range for the rows of array m. As a result, your program fails when you try to read the last row.

In addition, you have only two columns in your array `m`. Thus, when the `j` index changes from 0 to 3 you also have incorrect write to the memory.